# dynamically setting sort in an unordered list

Tags: jquery, sorting, jquery-ui

Ok, here's the issue I'm facing right now. I have a dynamically generated unordered list. Whoever originally wrote the code set up the UL to be sortable via the list items (i.e. you can switch out #1 and #2 on the list, etc.)

That code looks kinda like this:

```
$("#ulFeatures").sortable({
    update: function(event, ui) {
        var newOrder = $(this).sortable('toArray').toString();
    }
});
```

The new sort order is then saved to the database.

Well, the new requirement is that we should be able to lock certain ones in place.

I've used a checkbox a db field to determine whether or not it should be locked (bit, 1 = lock, 0 = unlock), but I can't figure out how to lock *individual* ones, based on their ID.

Any thoughts? How would I do this without writing a **bunch** more jQuery?

Comment: `$('.sortable').sortable('disable');` isn't there something like this to disable sortable ?

Comment: You can use the [`items`](https://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-items) option to specify a selector for the items that are sortable. Put a class selector in there, and only put the class on unlocked items.

Comment: @melvin That disables sorting completely, not just on individual items.

Comment: I believe so, if I have, say, 10 items and each <li> has its own ID (say, id=100, id=101, id=102, etc) and I only want to disable sort for 100 and 102, that's the issue I'm having.

Comment: @Barmar ok . got it.

Comment: @Barmar could you point me to an example of that? I'm not that familiar with using "items" as you describe.

Comment: I gave you a link to the documentation. There's not much more to it. Put `class="sortable"` on the sortable items, and use `items: "> .sortable"`

Comment: Oh, sorry...didn't see the link. I'll check it out.

Comment: @Barmar, you get the official upvote for the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`items`](https://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-items) option.

```
$("#ulFeatures").sortable({
    items: "> li.unlocked",
    ...
});
```

Then put `class="unlocked"` on the items that have `locked = 0`.