# .addClass() and .removeClass() with dynamically named elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Ok, this is related to a previous question I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50613460/dynamically-setting-sort-in-an-unordered-list)

The issue I'm facing now is that the LI elements have dynamic IDs. So what I want to do is, when an element with a dynamically generated ID is clicked, either add or remove a class from it.

Say the dynamically generated values are 1001, 1234, 4321, and 5678.

And based on the previous question, when they check/uncheck a checkbox, it triggers a click event.

But say they check the box for 4321 (remember, dynamically generated), I want to **remove** a class associated with the element 4321.

Code-wise, here's what I have:

```
if (chkVal === true) {
    $(elmId).removeClass("sortable");
} else {
    $(elmId).addClass("sortable");
}
```

In this snippet, elmId is the actual element (with a dynamically generated ID), the chkVal variable is checking whether or not the checkbox is checked or not.

So where am I going wrong here? Something tells me it's how I'm trying to access the elmId in the $(elmId) part of the code.

It also occurred to me that I might need to check for "true" instead of just checking for true (the boolean).

Comment: Put a common class on the dynamic checkboxes, then use a single delegated event handler on that class. Then you can use DOM traversal to affect the related content. By doing it in this manner the generated id (which I assume is unknown at runtime) is irrelevant.

Comment: "elmId is the actual element"...you mean it's a DOM object, or just a string containing the ID? Please be clear. If it's a string like "4321", you probably need to do `$("#"+elmId)` to make it a valid selector. Or do what Rory said, which will be neater.

Comment: whats the value of `elmId`? Is it a proper selector, e.g. `#myid` and not `myid`?

Comment: Ok, to clarify: elmID is just a string containing the ID (such as 3456) and not a proper selector.

Comment: Well that's not going to work, you need to turn it [into a selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50625286/addclass-and-removeclass-with-dynamically-named-elements#comment88260562_50625286)

Comment: Great comments, everyone. I'm starting off with ADyson's solution, and refactoring to Rory McCrossan's suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
if (chkVal === true) {
    $("#" + elmId).removeClass("sortable");
} else {
    $("#" + elmId).addClass("sortable");
}
```

If `elmId` is an ID number, like: `<input type="checkbox" id="1234" />` then to use it as a selector, you need to select it like so: `$("#1234")`.

Comment: That's basically what ADyson suggested above.

Comment: @MJR yes it is, and I hadn't seen that comment when I posted.