# Re-sort list items based on specific element value and position with jQuery

Tags: jquery, sorting, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

Ok, I have a LI with, let's say, 15 items in it. This relates to the previous question [I asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50613460/dynamically-setting-sort-in-an-unordered-list)

Well, I got that part figured out for the most part. But what they want now is that when I click the checkbox of an item, it dynamically moves to the "front" of the list behind other checked items.

In other words, at first when there are no items checked, they're just in whatever order that matches the DB. But if you click the "lock" on the 5th one, for instance, it should be checked, and automatically move to the 1st position in the list. So then if they click the "lock" on the 7th one, it should move to the 2nd position in the list, and so forth.

Each item in the LI has it's own unique ID, so I don't think it'll be a problem. I'm just not sure how to do this in jQuery.

Per request, here's the *current* code I have (this is as far as I've gotten):

```js
var checkedPos = 0;
$('input[id^="theId"]').on('click',
  function() {
    var theId = this.id.slice(5);
    var chkVal = this.checked;
    var suppId = <%= Request.QueryString["pid"]%>;

    if (chkVal === true) {
      updateRecordLock(theId, suppId, chkVal, checkedPos);
      checkedPos++;
      $("#" + theId).removeClass("sortable");
    } else {
      checkedPos--;
      updateRecordLock(theId, suppId, chkVal, null);
      $("#" + theId).addClass("sortable");
    }
  });
```

What I want to do is the following:

1. If it's the first item checked, it goes to the front of the list.
2. If there's already an item (or items) checked, the currently checked item goes to the *end* of the checked items.
3. If the user *unchecks* a currently checked item, it goes to the very end of the checked list, but as unchecked.

Comment: If you can provide code I can help better. Check the function .prependTo (http://api.jquery.com/prependto/) - Its copy element and put in selected other element to front (pre)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I decided to come back with my solution.

First, I started off doing this:

```
var checkedPos = $('input[id^="theId"]:checked').length;
```

That gave me the *count* of the number of items that were already checked.

then, inside my click event I did the code above, from my original post.Except I added an "index" to the conditionals that I either did a +1 or -1 on, to get the right index value.

Then at the end, I did something like this:

```
$("#" + theId).insertAfter("#myList li:nth-child(" + index + ")");
```

Which allowed me to "re-order" the list by putting the checked one into a new position, without refreshing the page.